# The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT , Android 5.0 this is happening

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, android-emulator

I tried almost all the solution but still no luck, but can anyone guide me like why this memory issue happening? and best possible way to solve this?

Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT
The device might have stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).

I am getting this error and i dont understand why just only on android 5.0 this is happening with my appplication.

How can i resolve this problem? Any good android developer can guide please help me in this?

i try delete user data and restart computer also

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. :-(

Comment: I have the same error on the real device. Nothing helps, I even tried to restore the device to the default state. But if I assemble apk and then run it on device - application installs successfully. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The error "The device might have stale dexed jars" often occurs together with low memory/storage space on the device.

If you're working with an emulator on a macOS-system I suggest the following steps:

1. Stop the emulator
2. Open Terminal and navigate to the emulator's data on the filesystem 
   `cd ~/.android/avd/[emulator_name].avd/`
3. In this directory there are some files ending with `.lock`, remove them: `rm *.lock`
4. Next step is to wipe the emulator's data, you can do this with the AVD Manager in Android Studio
5. Finally: Install your app on the wiped emulator

I hope these steps are helping you!